# c# object behaviour with polymorphism

Tags: c#, .net, oop, polymorphism

I'm trying to solve a problem involving polymorphism that's giving me headaches. The code is like this:

```c#
public abstract class Base
{
   public int val {get;set;}
   public virtual bool merge(Base obj) { return false; }
}

public class A : Base
{
   public override bool merge(Base obj)
   {
      /* If obj is of type A sum the "val" and return true, otherwise retur false */
   }
}

public class B : Base
{
   public override bool merge(Base obj)
   {
      /* If obj is of type B sum the "val" and return true, otherwise retur false */
   }
}

public class Composite
{
   List<Base> objects;
   public void addObject(Base obj)
   {
      foreach(Base b in this.objects)
      {
          if (b.merge(obj))
              return;
      }

      this.objects.Add(obj);
   }
}
```

What I'm trying to achieve is, upon adding an obj to the Composite class, to make the object being added "merge" to that with same type, otherwise to add it to the list. I'd like to code this behaviour without using 'if' statements or checking the object type
EDIT: when adding an object to the Composite class, i'd like to have the object inside the Composite to be updated with the value of the object being added. So if I have:

```c#
Composite C = new Composite();
C.addObject(new A(2));
C.addObject(new B(10));
// here C has { (A,2) , (B,10) }
C.addObject(new A(1));
// here C should have { (A,3) , (B,10) }
```

So far I came up with a slightly complicated solution which doesn't involves 'if' statements:

```c#
public abstract class Base
{
   public int val {get;set;}
   public virtual bool tryMerge(Base obj) { return false; }
   public virtual bool mergeA(A obj)  { return false; }
   public virtual bool mergeB(B obj)  { return false; }
}

public class A : Base
{
   public override bool tryMerge(Base obj)
   {
      return obj.mergeA(this);
   }

   public override bool mergeA(A obj)
   {
      obj.val += this.val;
      return true;
   }
}

public class B : Base
{
   public override bool merge(Base obj)
   {
      return obj.mergeB(this);
   }

   public override bool mergeB(B obj)
   {
      obj.val += this.val;
      return true;
   }
}

public class Composite
{
   List<Base> objects;
   public void addObject(Base obj)
   {
      foreach(Base b in this.objects)
      {
          if (b.tryMerge(obj))
              return;
      }

      this.objects.Add(obj);
   }
}
```

Any suggestion?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's not clear what should happen to the sum of the `val` values. Should it be assigned to the `val` property of the object itself, the parameter object, or both?

Comment: Also, the `mergeA` and `mergeB` methods should not exit. There should just be  `merge` method in the base, which is overridden in both `A` and `B`, as in the example code above.

Comment: It seems that you are asking for a better algorithm, then you should ask your question at http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: When you call `addObject(obj)` the first item in the Composite.objects that matches your `obj` type will be merged and the rest of the items with similar types in Coposite class will be ignored. Are you aware of this?

Comment: CarbineCoder I'm aware of that, but Composite should have only one object for every type extending Base. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach is not bad, although you should declare `mergeA` and `mergeB` functions as protected since they should not be exposed, but you would need some type check and casting before calling `mergeA` and `mergeB`.

Another approach would be defining this in the base class (without overloading any of these functions):

```
public abstract class Base
{
   public int val {get;set;}
   public bool merge(Base obj) { 
     if(obj.GetType() != this.GetType())
       return false;

     this.val += obj.val;

     return true;
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Joanvo! I've considered that, and in fact, it's what I did. I just wanted to try to avoid 'if' and GetType() ;)

As for the 'protected', if I declare mergeA and mergeB as 'protected' I won't be able to call them from the derived class, since I'm calling them on objects of type 'Base'

Comment: Hi ANVerona, you'd propably need `if` statements for type checking anyway. By the way, `protected` functions and members in a base class can bee seen by derived classes (they're not like `private`).

Comment: If they are protected they can't be called from derived classes on obj of type Base. Compiler says:  Cannot access protected member 'Base.mergeA(A)' via a qualifier of type 'Base'; the qualifier must be of type 'A' (or derived from it)

Answer (score 0):

```
public abstract class Base
    {
        public int val { get; set; }

        public abstract bool Merge<T>(T obj) where T:Base;
    }

    public class A : Base
    {
        public A(int val)
        {
            this.val = val;
        }

        public override bool Merge<A>(A obj)
        {
            if (obj.GetType() != GetType())
                return false;

            val += obj.val;
            return true;
        }
    }

    public class B : Base
    {
        public B(int val)
        {
            this.val = val;
        }

        public override bool Merge<B>(B obj)
        {
            if (obj.GetType() != GetType())
                return false;

            val += obj.val;
            return true;
        }
    }

    public class Composite
    {
        List<Base> objects = new List<Base>();

        public void addObject(Base obj)
        {
            foreach (Base b in this.objects)
            {
                if (b.Merge(obj))
                    return;
            }

            this.objects.Add(obj);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Low Flying Pelican, but using the "GetType" approach you can just write a Merge method inside the base class, and it works perfectly, without duplicating code and generic type. :)